# Libreoffice tabbed ribbons looks bad on XFCE

Tags: xubuntu, libreoffice, xfce

I have just enabled "tabbed ribbons" style user interface following some tutorials online. The expected result was something like this:

[image: Enable Tabbed Ribbon interface]

However what I see is this:

[image: Graybird]

or even worse with a dark theme:

[image: Graybird-dark]

Has anybody enabled this feature on XFCE?

I am using Xubuntu 22.04.2.

Thank you.

Comment: xfce is using your current gtk theme. It looks like you're using Greybird, the default Xubuntu theme. You can check your current theme opening the **Appearance** settings dialog. You need to install the same gtk theme and fonts from your first screenshot to get the same look. To fix your third screenshot, you need to select a dark icon theme in LibreOffice using `Options > Tools > View > Icon Theme`.